# :wq in Vim does not save

Tags: vim

I am trying to use `:wq` to save a text file I have edited in Vim, but when I enter `:wq` I get the error

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)`
```

When I add `!` to `:wq` like `:wq!`, I get this:

```
"/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf"

"/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

The file I want to edit is `dhcpd` on the `/etc/dhcpd` path.

How can I do this?

Comment: Prefer `:x` or `ZZ` to exit and save. It will write only on change.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to open the file using superuser permissions as follows:

```
sudo vi /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

edit the file by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> and then save and exit by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then either `:wq` or `:x` or just `:w` to save.

---

Thanks to [Riking](https://askubuntu.com/users/46171/riking) for suggesting `sudoedit`: you can use `sudoedit /path/to/file/filename` for editing files owned by root rather than using `sudo <editor> /pat/to/file/filename`. This is useful for enterprise-level machines or production machines since sudoedit logs to `/var/log/auth.log`.

If you want to change the default editor for sudoedit, do the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

and then press <kbd>Return</kbd> and choose the editor of your choice and again press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

---

See also: [A discussion on redit on why sudoedit may be advantegeous](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1a88kc/whats_so_great_about_sudoedit/)

Comment: I prefer `sudoedit` for these situations - it creates a temporary copy, runs the editor, and copies the result. If you previously chose `nano` for that command, run `EDITOR=vi sudoedit /etc/file`.

Comment: @Riking: Thanks for `sudoedit`, didn't even know it existed. However, came across [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/239/recommending-sudoedit-instead-of-sudo-editor) while googling `sudoedit`. I'll suggest it, but leave it to the user if they find it necessary to use.

Comment: `sudoedit` also picks up on the `EDITOR` variable, it's easier to set that than configure alternatives

Answer (score 10):

`/etc` consists of all configurations files so to edit the files under `/etc` you need the superuser permissions but sometime we forget to use `sudo`. 
but at that time we can also use

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

then enter your administrator password

```
:q!
```

to exit successfully

Comment: You can add `cmap w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %` to your `.vimrc` to allow saving via this method with `:w!!`. If you're interested in why this method works see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work