# vim unable to write to files even though sudo is used

Tags: sudo, root, vim, privileges, elevation

I find that with `vim`, if I try and edit a file which as a normal user I do not have write access with, even if I use `sudo`, I am unable to write to it, although if I use `nano` to edit the same file it works.

So for instance if I do:

```
sudo vim /var/path/to/file.conf
```

I will get this in the file and not be able to edit that file:

```
"/var/path/to/file.conf" [readonly]
```

But if I instead do:

```
sudo nano /var/path/to/file.conf
```

It will be able to write to the file, why is this, why does `sudo` not give `vim` write access like it does with `nano`? Is this some sort of bug? Or is this just something which is meant to be? Because it is very annoying.

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

```
vim:
  Installed: 2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It could be hosted on a read-only filesystem. run `mount` to see if `/var/path/to` is located in the output, then post what filesystem type it's on.

Comment: @NuclearPeon `nano` can write to the file, so it's not on a readonly filesystem.

Comment: Although there is already an accepted answer, maybe this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/471776/wq-on-vim-does-not-save - could be a difference between `vi` and `vim`

Comment: @NuclearPeon In [that question](https://askubuntu.com/q/471776), the user cannot override lack of write permissions because they do not own the file. The file is owned by root and set writeable only by root; thus one must `sudo` to root to edit it (or use `sudoedit`, which does the same thing behind the scenes on exit). Since the file has write permissions set for root, `!` isn't needed to save changes when editing it as root. In *this question*, the user owns the file, but it's (probably) not set writable for anyone, so there's no reason to edit as root (and `!` is needed even with `sudo`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of vim (and vi).

When you edit a readonly file, attempting to write the file the usual way (with `:w`) fails. This is to prevent you from accidentally changing a readonly file you might not wish to change.

If you *really* want to override the readonly permissions on a file that you own, and write your changes to the file, **you must use the `:w!` command** so vim knows this is what you want.

- This is similar to how `:q` will not quit if there are unsaved changes, but `:q!` will.

If you want to write any changes and quit in one command, you can use `:wq!` or `:x!`.

Comment: This will also happen if you've accessed the file with `-R`. you could read about this and more with `:help readonly` from within vim, from the manpages.

Comment: It wont work when using sudo, even with :w! any idea?

Comment: If it doesn't work, even with w!, perhaps the file has an immutable attribute set. See here for more info and details on how to remove it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67509/365977