# E45 readonly option is set (add ! to override)

Tags: server, phpmyadmin, extension

I'm trying to configure the extension mcrypt in my Ubuntu Server VirtualBox for work in my phpMyAdmin page.

I ran `vi /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini` and then I changed `extension=mcrypt.so` to `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.­so` and when I tried to save changes it said this:

```
E45 readonly option is set (add ! to override)
```

I think that maybe I made a mistake deleting something before `extension=mcrypt.os` and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:wq on vim does not save](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471776/wq-on-vim-does-not-save)

Comment: Try opening the file with ``sudo vi /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28635648

Answer (score 37):

Probably the user you ran `vi /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini` as did not have write access to the file. `vi` notices this on file open, and, when you try to save the file, gives you the `E45`error, and reminds you that you could attempt to override the read-onlyness of the file by appending `'!'` to the command.

For example, if you edited a file owned by your user, protected `444 (r--r--r--)`, you would get this message when you did the `:wq`, but could try to force the write with `:wq!`. In your case, I suggest doing `ls -l /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`. To actually edit the file, you could use `sudo` to temporarily use the power of `root`, and do `sudo vi /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`

Comment: Thank you , i use sudo before vim then i could edit source.list

Comment: Doesn't seem like a permission problem. In my case: ``getfacl file.sh;
# file: file.sh
# owner: me
# group: thegroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x``
But I still get the error! As soon as I press "i", this appears ``-- INSERT (paste) -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file``, after making some changes, when I try to save I get ``E505: "file.sh" is read-only (add ! to override)``, Same permission also exist for the parent directory: ``# owner: me
# group: thegroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
``, this is really weird! And this is happening to any file that I create!

Answer (score 17):

You can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> , and then <kbd>U</kbd> , and then type `:q` .

You can try opening the file with `sudo` privilege: `sudo vi <file_name>`

Comment: Adding `sudo` works

Answer (score 14):

First come out of the vim editor using: `:qa!`

Next, use `sudo vim filename` and later: `:wq`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** This answer is identical to the [highest upvoted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635789/344926)

Answer (score 10):

Try the below command

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Explanation, What's happening?

- :w – write
- !sudo – call shell sudo command
- tee – the output of write (:w) command is redirected using tee
- % – current file name

So, in next Press `L` to reload.

just this!!!

Comment: This is particularly helpful if you have made a ton of changes and do not want to close the file and reopen using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the user is trying to write on a file without the right permissions. Login as root using `sudo su` and now you can do the edit...