# When I modify /etc/security/limits.conf I get "E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)"

Tags: command-line, permissions, nano, vi, resource-limiting

I'm trying to increase the open files limit for Ubuntu 16.04 version by using `vi /etc/security/limits.conf` Then I add two lines like:

```
#* soft nofile 4096
#* hard nofile 4096
```

But when I use `:x` to save and exit I get `E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)` and it doesn't exit.

When I use `nano etc/security/limits.conf` to modify it I get:

```
Error writing /etc/security/limits.conf: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc is a system directory that a users account will not (or should not) have access to.

You need to use `sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf` was required, ie. the use of `sudo` elevates privileges for the command following the `sudo`.

Comment: Also, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/471777/659265), you could use `sudoedit /etc/security/limits.conf` if your machine is an enterprise-level one, since it logs the action to `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: @DiogoVilela I would go further and suggest `sudoedit` even on a non-production machine used by only one person. It can be used [with just about any editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161271/22949) and it [uses the user's editor configuration automatically (and without causing permissions problems)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162664/22949).